# Avoid duplicates in SQL server due the latency

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a POS like system in C#, and for long time it not present any problem (it was just one POS). But in this days are 4 POS using the system, and connected to the same database and all the sales of one POS go to the same Audit (table) where all of the others sales go.
So in this system this is the procedure

1. Function to get the last Ticket number (with simple SELECT)
2. Add 1 to that number (next tickt no).
3. Generates a ID Code injecting this Ticket number (with the terminal, date, and employee code) into the algorithm
4. Insert record of the sale into database with all the necesary information (Date, Client, Employee, IDCode, etc.) (with simple INSERT INTO)

But having 4 POS I realize that some sales where having the same Ticket number, fortunately the Ticket ID code are not the same because the terminal and the employee are different, but how can avoid this?

**Edit 1**:
Every POS system have dual function, in one mode the POS sales are centralized, and every POS in this mode generates consecutive tickets (like they all where one POS), in the other mode every POS have their own Ticket numertion, for that reason I can't use the identity.

Comment: You'd better show your code.

Comment: Databases have `identity` columns which generate the next number for you in a single atomic operation.  Don't generate it yourself in a multi-threaded environment because you can't guarantee that two operations won't occur at the same time.  Let the database generate the identifier.

Comment: Do not create record identifiers programmatically - let the database handle this (like David said) and use transactions for critical operations.

Comment: He says they are all going to one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a sequence to generate the next ticket number.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Tickets
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then each POS just do

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Tickets;
```

The sequence is guaranteed to never return the same number twice.

Comment: That's what I call and elegant solution! and solve others problems I had.

Comment: @CesarRomeroo This is nice. I had completely forgotten about SEQUENCEs for some reason ;-). I will just mention that IF you cannot have gaps in the ID numbers, then you need to test this out as I seem to recall it working similar to an IDENTITY in that if the INSERT fails for any reason, then the value will already be incremented the next time around. Don't get me wrong, if this works then by all means use it over what I recommended. Just do enough testing to ensure that it actually does work as you expect it to, especially in non-ideal situations. But +1 regardless :-) .

Comment: In case INSERT Fails, I was thinking to use an ALTER SECUENCE, may it work but (Assuming the extreme scenario of massive sale) can this generate a significant latency to make something get wrong?

Comment: @CesarRomeroo If a SEQUENCE works as I suspect (like an IDENTITY) then if an INSERT fails it will be too late to alter the SEQUENCE back to the prior value (and you won't know what that is). The entire reason for you posting this question was that more than 1 POS system was hitting this function at the same time. If one fails the other might not and now you have a gap in **TicketNumber**. If gaps are ok then all is well. But if you can't have gaps then a SEQUENCE won't help as it wasn't meant to do that. And in that case you really do need to single-thread the operation as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, if the TicketNumber is sequential and unique, it sounds like an IDENTITY field would be the way to go. BUT, if for some reason there is something preventing that, or if that requires too many changes as this time, you could constrain the process itself to be single-threaded by creating a lock on the ID Code generation process itself through the use of Application Locks (see [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx)). Application Locks let you create locks around arbitrary concepts. Meaning, you can define the `@Resource` as "generate_id_code" which will force each caller to wait their turn. It would follow this structure:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'generate_id_code', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';

    ...current 4 steps to generate the ID Code...

    EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'generate_id_code';
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You need to manage errors / ROLLBACK yourself (as stated in the linked MSDN documentation) so put in the usual TRY / CATCH.  But, this does allow you to manage the situation.

**Please note:** `sp_getapplock` / `sp_releaseapplock` should be used sparingly; Application Locks can definitely be very handy (such as in cases like this one) but they should only be used when absolutely necessary.

Comment: And will this even lock the SELECT command (the intention of retriving the last Ticket number while was already taked and already being processed for other Ticket)?

Comment: @CesarRomeroo It doesn't lock commands, it locks access beyond the point of the same `@Resource` value being requested by another process, whether using this same stored proc or another that is also using `sp_getapplock` with that `@Resource` value. That is the beauty of this, it is the gate keeper and does not require locking rows in tables. Just keep in mind that making the "ID Code Generation" process single-threaded will slow it down a little, but that is an inherent part of your request, which is not a problem if you add an IDENTITY field to the table and factor that value in instead.

Comment: @CesarRomeroo Meaning, if all 4 POS systems call this same proc at the same time, only 1 of them can get the lock. The other 3 will simply wait for this one to finish and release the lock, at which time 1 other will get it and the other 2 will be waiting still. But the while those other 3 are waiting, they are not blocked from issuing the SELECT specifically, they just can't proceed to the line that has the SELECT. So other processes are free to SELECT from that table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in an atomic action. So you can wrap everything in a transaction and lock the table. [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx#Lock_Basics) for a good discussion on locking etc.

Locking will slow down everything else since everything will start waiting for the table to free up for it to complete and that may not be something you can live with.

**Or you <del>can</del> should use an [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) on the column which will be managed by the database and maintain unique incrementing numbers.**

You could also create your primary key (hope you have one) to be a combination of a few things. And then you could keeping a running number for each POS endpoint to see more data about how they are performing. But that gets more into analytics which isn't in scope here.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest moving away from the current approach if you can and changing to a GUID PK.

However, I realize that in some cases a redesign is not possible (we have the exact same scenario that you describe in a legacy database).

In this case, you can get the maximum value safely using the [UPDLOCK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) table hint in combination with the insert command and use the `OUTPUT INSERTED` functionality to retrieve the new primary key value into a local variable if needed:

```
DECLARE 
  @PK Table (PK INT NOT NULL) 

INSERT 
  INTO Audit (
       TicketNumber, 
       Terminal,
       Date,
       EmployeeCode,
       Client,
       IDCode,
       ... other fields )
  /* Record the new PK in the tablevariable */
OUTPUT INSERTED.TicketNumber INTO @PK
SELECT IsNull(MAX(TicketNumber), 0) + 1, 
       @Terminal,
       @Date,
       @EmployeeCode,
       @Client,
       @IDCode,
       ... other values
  FROM Audit WITH (UPDLOCK)

DECLARE @TicketNumber INT

  /* Move the new PK from the local tablevariable into a local variable for subsequent use */
SELECT @TicketNumber = PK
  FROM @PK
```

Comment: This method of generating non-IDENTITY IDs and retrieving them immediately was obsolete as of SQL Server 2005, which introduced the `OUTPUT` clause. You would just add `OUTPUT INSERTED.TicketNumber INTO TempTableOrTableVariable (FieldName)` to the insert. Along those lines, they also introduced `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` which reduces fragmentation due to the random nature of GUIDs. I would _never_ recommend a GUID PK, especially if the PK is clustered. If you need a GUID, make it a unique, non-clustered index. Use that for lookups from the app, but use the Clustered INT PK for JOINs, etc.

Comment: That's a good posibility but just for clarify, this is pretending INSERT all the other ticket data first and then get the tickt number available?

Comment: @CesarRomeroo: No, in this approach you simultaneously insert the ticket data AND get the next available key all in one transaction. I had forgotten about the OUTPUT INSERTED mechanism that struzky mentions, which will make the operation more efficient. I will update the answer shortly with this info and add a few sample columns to show the full concept.

Comment: @CesarRomeroo As long as the `UPDLOCK` makes it so that the other 3 processes cannot select the same value at the same time _prior to getting that lock_, then this could work. It might lock other, non-related processes out of that table, though (at least without using NOLOCK). You need to test. But using OUTPUT means you can get rid of the GUID and the additional lookup (which I suspect will be reflected when competent_tech updates).

Comment: @srutzky: thanks for reminding me about output inserted. We had updated all of our code relatively recently to do this (once we were able to stop supporting SQL 2000) and I had forgotten all about it. As for the PK, the only reason I recommend against using identity (we use identity extensively) is the number of problems that we have had in transporting data from one DB to another (i.e. staging configuration to production) or rolling configuration into a customer's DB. Using identity requires a substantial amount of additional mapping work in these scenarios and things can go very wrong.

Comment: @competent_tech Understood about moving data between systems, though I would argue/suggest/mention that those cases should instead use a non-IDENTITY INT PK. If it is system lookup data (i.e. enum values) then those should be assigned the same values that they have in the app (if they exist in both places) and moved between system only via rollout script. No need for GUIDs :).